# Windows could not parse or process unattended answer file [unattended.xml] The specified file does not exist

Tags: sysprep

When you run SysPrep you get the error.

> Windows could not parse or process unattended answer file
>   [unattended.xml] The specified file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The error is just confusing. Basically this just means SysPrep is not running as administrator.

If you are running SysPrep on command line, make sure to start the command line as administrator and that fixes the issue.

Comment: Microsoft is the master of confusing error messages.